# How to use pygtk for windows 7/8?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pygtk

How to use pygtk on windows 7/8? Can I use pygtk to program GUI for windows applications? There are tutorials for linux os but none for windows, would be glad if someone can share.

Comment: I made instructions on this already.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567921/python-pygtk-windows-7-64-bit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PyGTK website](http://www.pygtk.org/):

> PyGTK applications are truly **multiplatform** and they're able to run,
>   unmodified, on Linux, Windows, MacOS X and other platforms.

All of the code and examples presented in the Linux tutorials that you mentioned should also run on Windows 7/8 (assuming you have the GTK libraries installed - you can get an all-in-one bundle for Windows from [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/)).

Comment: Thanks, I tried. But I get an error whenever I run the programs in my IDLE (I'm using windows 8).

Comment: Have you got the GTK+ runtime installed? And the PyGTK, PyCairo and PyObject modules installed? You can get these by following the [steps](http://www.pygtk.org/downloads.html) on the PyGTK website or by installing the [all-in-one bundle](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/).