# python gtkgl installation windows 7, 64x

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk

I followed the instructions in: [python pygtk windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567921/python-pygtk-windows-7-64-bit) to install pygtk (I'm using python 2.7). Now, however, I'm trying to install gtkgl to work with my python installation. I tried 2006 release from http://projects.gnome.org/gtkglext/download.html#pygtkglext but I can't run setup.py without errors.

2006 seems pretty old- is it even possible to use it with the newest pygtk?
How can I install it?

The error I get is:

```
File "pygtkglext-1.1.0\setup.py", line 89, in <module>
if not pkgc_version_check('pygtk-2.0', 'PyGTK', PYGTK_REQUIRED_VERSION):
TypeError: pkgc_version_check() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

but after commenting out line 89 and running the script again, I get:

```
Could not find code generator in %s, do you have installed pygtk correctly?
```

The gtk-demo seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Will it work for you?

http://www.stephanebrunet.net/gtkglext/

1234567

Comment: OOh, These are for python 2.4 and 2.5? Is there a python3 module equivalent do you know?

Comment: Today I wouldn't bother with pygtk. Better install PySide(or PyQT), it has QtOpenGL.QGLWidget. `pip install PySide`, `pip install PyOpenGL`, then run this example https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/raw/060dca8e4b82f301dfb33a7182767eaf8ad3d024:examples/opengl/hellogl.py