# No module named xml.etree.ElementTree in GTK, python

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm working with Python 2.7.6, Windows 8.1, in PyCharm 3.1.3.

trying to run something that already worked and get the error:

> File "C:\something\sources\ParamsWin.py", line 6, in 
>       import gtk ImportError: No module named gtk

Tried to download GTK through project settings, and got:

> ImportError: No module named xml.etree.ElementTree

Tried to import element tree package and got the same error.

I've been googling quite a bit and there seems to be a problem with python and this element.

anyone, ideas?

TIA

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed on your computer? Make sure your project is using the correct version.

Comment: I have the same version (2.7.6) in 32-bit and 64-bit. The 32-bit has GTK, but because we can't use other things with it we also have 64-bit. Now that has this GTK problem...

Answer (score 0):

You say you tried to download GTK?

I've had problems in the past (and the xml.etree... thing does look familiar) when I just installed GTK *on its own*. The best way of installing gtk in a Windows platform, in my humble opinion, is to use one of the the *all-in-one* downloaders from here: [http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/).

Cheers,
Simon

Comment: Ah, now you mention x64, it appears this question has already been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567921/python-pygtk-windows-7-64-bit. Hope it works for you!