# Installing python gtk on windows 7 64-bit

Tags: python, windows, gtk, pip, python-wheel

I'm trying to install python gtk on a windows 7 64-bit machine. I'm following

[python pygtk windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567921/python-pygtk-windows-7-64-bit)

to do so. I've followed steps 1-4 in this link, and all was fine, but on step 5 (installing the libraries gtk,PyCairo,goobject), there are no .exe's in the link. I followed comments in the answer, which say to pip install the .whl file. So I installed pip:

"pip --version" in CMD yields "pip 8.1.2 from c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages (python 3.5)".

Also,

"python --version" in CMD yields "Python 3.5.2".

Then, in CMD:

`>pip install pycairo_gtk-1.10.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
pycairo_gtk-1.10.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

So I then searched this online and found this post:

[filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

Which just seems to indicate that the filename needs to be of a particular format.

Question: Is the filename I downloaded somehow wrong? Or needs to be renamed?

I'm sorry if this is just a duplicate of the last link, but it seems to me that a step-by-step of installing python gtk is incomplete for windows 7 64-bit, which is the root of my question.

Comment: `cp27` part in that filename refers to python version 2.7, so that wheel is incompatible with python version 3.5.2 you have.

Comment: Ahh. I was having trouble installing pip, so I installed python 3.5.2 because it comes with it. I'm not sure what to do...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to install, but I sure hope it's _not_ pygtk (as in `import pygtk`). You should be able to install gtk3 (`from gi.repository import Gtk`) from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/). (When asked which components to install during the setup, make sure to check `Gtk+`.)