# Python 3.5 Installing Gtk + 3 (Windows computer)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation, gtk3

I'm building a tool with a GUI and I would like to try Gtk + 3. However after installing it through the the link here (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files) which I found on a similar posted question ([Installing python gtk on windows 7 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333259/installing-python-gtk-on-windows-7-64-bit)), I don't seem to be able to access the modules in Python.

Apart from downloading Gtk+3 and installing it, what do I need to do to be able to write 'import gi' and have it work?

Comment: Did you check out the documentation? (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/gtk3/4255/introduction-to-gtk3/14881/installation-or-setup#t=201609031324214892282)

Comment: Thanks BB8! Scanning through the details, I'm not sure if I should even be using Gtk. Ultimately I want to use something like pyinstaller to make something simple to distribute. With Gtk I guess each machine would need to have to be prepped so I'm guessing I will proceed with tkinter (ugly but simple).

Comment: GTK + Pyinstaller will work, but only if you use the latest version of pyinstaller :)

Comment: OK I'll take a look and see if the guide you posted solves the problem :)

Comment: Gtk3 isn't available for Python 3.5 yet, use Python 3.4 instead.

Comment: Ok I didn't know that. Do you think that's why I installed everything but I couldn't get the library to Work?